# How to fix the following grub error ?

Tags: grubrescue

I am getting a huge problem, I installed Ubuntu only 10/12 days before. Today , when I ran my PC, it shows a black screen just like CMD . and here are the messages :

```
error:file'grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> [here is the cursor]
```

now I got some solutions before, I tried the following approach :

```
>ls
(hd0,msdos2)(hd0,msdos1)(hd0,msdos 5) #.....I saw such things
```

then I found the filesystem of (hd0,msdos1) is ext2.
then ,

```
>set boot=(hd0,msdos1)
>set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
>insmod normal
>normal
```

But when I give the command **insmod normal** , a command **not found** is shown, please help me :'(

Answer (score 0):

I think, that your boot partition is broken. Try boot from livecd/live usb to fix it.

First, find your harddrive using `lsblk` command. 
Check filsystem for errors.
Then check if your boot partition is not full. It may be necessary to delete some previous versions of kernels or images.

Then mount your root partition and bot partition, bind `/sys`, `/proc`, `/dev`, `/run`directories, `chroot` to this space and `update-grub2`.
Reboot.

Something like this:

```
lsblk

NAME                       MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO MOUNTPOINT
sda                          8:0    0 298.1G  0
├─sda1                       8:1    0   500M  0 
└─sda2                       8:2    0 297.6G  0
  ├─vg_main-lv_swap (dm-0) 253:0    0   5.8G  0 
  ├─vg_main-lv_root (dm-1) 253:1    0    50G  0 
  └─vg_main-lv_home (dm-2) 253:2    0 241.8G  0
    └─home (dm-3)          253:3    0 241.8G  0 
sr0                         11:0    1  1024M  0
```

## Check boot partition for errors

```
fsck /dev/sda1
```

## Mount harddrive root partition

```
mount /dev/dev/vg_main-lv_root /mnt
```

Or something like this depending yours disk layout

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

## Mount boot

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
```

## Bind directories

```
 for x in proc dev sys run ; do
      mount -o bind /${x} /mnt/${x}
 done
```

## Chroot and reinstall grub

```
  chroot /mnt
  grub-install /dev/sda
  grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
  exit
```

## Cleanup and reboot

```
cd /
umount /mnt/boot /mnt/sys /mnt/proc /mnt/dev /mnt/run /mnt
reboot
```

Comment: "Then mount your root partition and bot partition, bind /sys, /proc, /dev, /rundirectories, chroot to this space and update-grub2. Reboot."

I couldn't catch what to do here , pelase help me again

Comment: This was a summery what, should be done. I wrote the details  lower. Step by step.